# php how to include a file from a different root

Tags: php

For my website [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) I have a folder structure like this:

```
root
/login
/includes
```

In the folder login I have login.php with (simplified):

```
<?php
  include_once('../includes/includes.php');
?>
```

If I access `www.mysite.com/login/login.php` the include works just fine, but if I access `login.mysite.com/login.php` the include doesn't work.

How can I get this to work?

I've tried using `$_SERVER["document_root"]` in the include, and I've tried with `www.mysite.com/includes/includes.php`.

Suggestions are much appreciated.

*Edit:* Unfortunately I don't have access to php.ini as I am on a web-hotel.

Comment: Side note (not question related: i recommend using `require_once()` instead.

Comment: Use an absolute path or make use of include path. https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to php.ini as I am on a web-hotel.

Comment: a combination of `__DIR__` (magic constant), `chdir()`, `getcwd()` and `set_include_path()` are most useful when setting a path to files for inclusion (either using `require` or `include` etc ). You can store a reference to the current working directory with `getcwd()` for later use if you set different include paths or whatever

Comment: Thanks. set_include_path() did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Professor Abronsius:
a combination of `__DIR__ (magic constant), chdir(), getcwd()` and `set_include_path()` are most useful when setting a path to files for inclusion (either using require or include etc ).
 You can store a reference to the current working directory with `getcwd()` for later use if you set different include paths or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

easy way with ssh you can Symlink file to anther locate file

```
ln -s my_folder/includes.php includes2.php
```

then use your include

```
  include_once('includes2.php');
```